# extract value from json array of API response without brackets not working

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

Here is JSON:

```
{
"first":0,
"rows":100,
"data":[
{
"id":326,
"tag":"QATA9",
"workNo":"qat12345"
}
],
"totalRecords":1
}
```

And my code is :

```
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
wID = jsonPathEvaluator.get("data.id");
System.out.println("id is "+ wID);

String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
```

In output it shows 
[326]
But i need value only 326

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` delimits an array, so the library is treating it as an array. Just pick the first element, and you should be fine.

Try this:

```
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
wID = jsonPathEvaluator.get("data.id")[0];
System.out.println("id is "+ wID);
```

Then, again, you should also have in mind that, the fact that an array was used in the first place may indicate that you may have more than one element; in that case, you should simply loop through the array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
wID = jsonPathEvaluator.get("data[0].id");
System.out.println("id is "+ wID);
```